# What does this line conditional statement in java mean?

Tags: java

```
(comparison > 0 ? n : m).subtract(comparison > 0 ? m : n);
```

I'm trying to figure out what this inline conditional statement means and how to convert it into a regular if statement. The .subtract is just a method that will subtract the second () from the first().

I think that the first (comparison > 0 ? n : m) is the same as `if(comparison > 0) { m = n; }`
not sure how that works with the subtract function. The code runs correctly but I'm trying to fix the warning to not use inline conditionals.

Thank you!

Comment: Compile it, step through with a debugger then you will see

Comment: It's [conditional operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25)

Answer (score 3):

The ternary `?:` operator is what is used here.

```
a ? b : c means

if (a) {
   b;
} else {
   c;
}
```

So `(comparison > 0 ? n : m).subtract(comparison > 0 ? m : n);` means.

```
if (comparsion > 0) {
    n.subtract(m);
} else {
    m.subtract(n);
}
```

In this case n and m must be `objects` that have a `subtract` method as follows which prints:

> result = -3 when comparison = -5
>   result = 3 when comparison = 5

```
public class TernaryDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int comparison : new int[] { -5, 5 }) {
            MyClass n = new MyClass(10);
            MyClass m = new MyClass(7);
            MyClass result = (comparison > 0 ? n : m)
                    .subtract(comparison > 0 ? m : n);

            System.out.println("result = " + result
                    + " when comparison = " + comparison);
        }
    }
}

class MyClass {
    int v;

    public MyClass(int v) {
        this.v = v;
    }

    public MyClass subtract(MyClass cls) {
        return new MyClass(this.v - cls.v);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return v + "";
    }

}
```

Comment: Unless, unfortunately, `subtract` returns `void`, in which case you can't use the ternary in plain Java (Groovy and Kotlin will allow it).

Comment: Yep:  I updated the answer to include a demo.

Answer (score 2):

This is stuff you can test yourself.

However, it translates to:

```
Subtractable sub, sub2; // This is how I am going to call the class that has the subtract method

if(comparison > 0)
    sub = n;
else
    sub = m;

// You could put these in the same if statement, but this is closer to what actually happens.
if(comparison > 0)
    sub2 = m;
else
    sub2 = n;

sub.subtract(sub2);
```